# XSLT checking for an attribute, how do I make it "do nothing" if that attribute is not in a known set of values?

Tags: xml, xslt, ccd

I am working with a CCD XML document, it contains data like this:

```
<tr ID="encounter17" >
    <td>09/18/2012</td>
    <td ID="type41">Office Visit</td>
    <td>Family Practice</td>
    <td>
        <paragraph>REDACTED</paragraph>
    </td>
    <td />
</tr>
<tr ID="encounter18" styleCode="altRow">
    <td>09/17/2012</td>
    <td ID="type42">Office Visit</td>
    <td>Family Practice</td>
    <td>
        <paragraph>REDACTED</paragraph>
    </td>
    <td />
</tr>
```

I am trying to render this as HTML using the "standard" CCD.xsl, `Derived from HL7 Finland R2 Tyylitiedosto: Tyyli_R2_B3_01.xslt
                Updated by Calvin E. Beebe, Mayo Clinic - Rochester Mn.`

The element with the ID `encounter17` will render, the element with the ID `encounter18` will not render. Looking at the output of `xsltproc` this is happening because the XSLT does not recognize the `styleCode` attribute. Only `Bold, Italic, Underline` are supported.

How can I change this XSLT so that it tolerates an unknown styleCode?

```
<!--    Stylecode processing
  Supports Bold, Underline and Italics display-->
<xsl:template match="//n1:*[@styleCode]">

<xsl:if test="@styleCode='Bold'">
    <xsl:element name='b'>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="@styleCode='Italics'">
    <xsl:element name='i'>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="@styleCode='Underline'">
    <xsl:element name='u'>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="contains(@styleCode,'Bold') and contains(@styleCode,'Italics') and not (contains(@styleCode, 'Underline'))">
    <xsl:element name='b'>
        <xsl:element name='i'>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="contains(@styleCode,'Bold') and contains(@styleCode,'Underline') and not (contains(@styleCode, 'Italics'))">
    <xsl:element name='b'>
        <xsl:element name='u'>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="contains(@styleCode,'Italics') and contains(@styleCode,'Underline') and not (contains(@styleCode, 'Bold'))">
    <xsl:element name='i'>
        <xsl:element name='u'>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="contains(@styleCode,'Italics') and contains(@styleCode,'Underline') and contains(@styleCode, 'Bold')">
    <xsl:element name='b'>
        <xsl:element name='i'>
            <xsl:element name='u'>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

I have already tried adding:

```
<xsl:if test="not (contains(@styleCode,'Italics')) and not (contains(@styleCode,'Underline')) and not (contains(@styleCode, 'Bold'))">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:if>
```

This seems to just render the element, it doesn't "fall through" to the part of the XSLT that deals with the `<tr>` tag.

Comment: What do you mean by 'This seems to just render the element, it doesn't "fall through" to the part of the XSLT that deals with the `<tr>` tag.'? The whole template you showed is dealing with the `<tr>` tag. What is the desired output, in contrast to the actual output?

Comment: The desired output is for `encounter17` and `encounter18` to each be a separate row. With the original XSLT, `encounter18` is not rendered because of the unrecognized value in `styleCode`. With my attempted changes `encounter18` shows up as additional columns in the same row as `encounter17` instead of a separate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What horrible code! In 2.0 you want to do it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:*[contains(@styleCode,'Bold')]" priority="100">
  <b><xsl:next-match/></b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n1:*[contains(@styleCode,'Italic')]" priority="99">
  <i><xsl:next-match/></i>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n1:*[contains(@styleCode,'Underline')]" priority="98">
  <u><xsl:next-match/></u>
</xsl:template>
```

That's essentially all. This will ignore any stylecode not in the list.

You can do the same thing in 1.0 using xsl:apply-imports, but the three rules then need to be in separate stylesheet modules.

Comment: Can you show how do this in 1.0? Since I'm modifying an XSLT that is a de facto standard, and it is written in 1.0 I want to keep using 1.0 to be as compatible as possible.

Comment: Put each of the template rules shown into a different module; change the xsl:next-match to xsl:apply-imports; and arrange it so that each module imports the one shown with next lower priority (the priority will be ignored in this scenario).

Comment: Whoops, I just broke my self-imposed rule that I don't do XSLT 1.0 these days. I'll be answering COBOL questions next.

Comment: Replacing "next-match" with "apply-imports" worked for me. Thanks a lot.